# How to pass date value in Rest API parameter using Azure Data factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, rest

I have a API Url which having one of the parameter with TIMESTAMP.The Url will be like

Actual Url: https://mtplace.api.onoc.com/V2/products/00vkxX?app_id=adm12&access_mdm=computer&TIMESTAMP=2020-07-17T11%3A09%3A25Z&hash_code=O2cnasnajsaBz4qMdKDV3xw2mniiiRQasCuEv65auvjCs%3D

and time stamp value is 2020-07-17T11%3A09%3A25Z.
I want to avoid timestamp value to become expire and for that i created a parameter TS with value utcNow().  And using that parametr in urllike

https://mtplace.api.onoc.com/V2/products/00vkxX?app_id=adm12&access_mdm=computer&TIMESTAMP=dataset().TS&hash_code=O2cnasnajsaBz4qMdKDV3xw2mniiiRQasCuEv65auvjCs%3D

am using this Url to connect rest api service as source in ADF. I am trying to replace Timestampvalue with a parameter value utcNow(). But i am failing with error Expected EOF, found ':' at 6.

Can you help me how can i replace timestamp value from 2020-07-1217T11%3A09%3A25Z to system to avoid timevalue expiration.

Answer (score 0):

Store these values in variables and then concatenate.

Comment: I added a parameter called TS and its value like utcNow(). And called this parameter in url with parameter Timestamp=dataset().ts

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp parameter needs URL encoding. I could not find any inbuilt function for encoding. So alternative way is to use a dataflow and column derivation with replace function ( replace ':' with '%3A' and space with 'T'). You may need some more transformations.

Then, timestamp '2020-07-19 19:50:40.851' can be passed as '2020-07-19T19%3A50%3A40Z'